# Sumar valores por categoría especifica y mostrarlo en otra celda (google sheets)

Tags: excel, google-hoja-de-cálculo

como puedo hacer para sumar todos los registros de tipo "comida" de un rango sumarlos y mostrarlo en una sola celda, como podrán ver en la imagen el resultado debería ser `8` pero muestra un error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

`=sumifs($C$27:$C$35,$E$27:$E$35,B7)`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, gracias por la guia, simplemente a tu formula inverti los 2 primeros y me sumo bien sumifs($F$27:$F$35;B7;$C$27:$C$35)

Comment: Si esta respuesta te ha ayudado, por favor, márcala como correcta